# Disable Remember Password of browser in ASP.NET windows auth mode

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication

How we can disable 'Remember Password' of browser in ASP.NET application while we are using windows authentication mode? and is it possible that we can handle it through code?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting:

`autocomplete="off"` in the form tag.

```
<form id="form" method="post" autocomplete="off">
```

Comment: No,this is for end user but we need it fix from over end. As we are vendor of application n we need to disable 'Remember Password' option for user of application for due to security reason.

Comment: Thank you KPL, but this working in case of form authentication by puting these tags on Password field but i am windows authentication mode.